# rails find_or_initialize on relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

when I create a new user, to avoid duplicates, I use the find_or_initialize method:

```
user = find_or_initialize_by_email(the_email)
```

If this user is created with a related company, how can I avoid the duplicates in companies?

Can I do something like:

```
find_or_initialize_by_email_and_by_company_name(the_email, the_company_name)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Rails 3.2 way is

```
User.where(email: the_email, company_name: the_company_name).first_or_initialize
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
find_or_initialize_by_email_and_company_name(the_email, the_company_name)
```

you will create users uniq both by email and company name.
(by is used only once)